# Reading binary file data into List of Structs

Tags: c#, struct, binaryfiles

I have a simple procedure to write a list of library books (of type TBook) to a binary file as follows:

```
static void SaveToFile(List<TBook> lib)
    {
        FileStream currentFile;
        BinaryWriter writerToFile;
        currentFile = new FileStream("MyLibrary.bin", FileMode.Create);
        writerToFile = new BinaryWriter(currentFile);
        foreach (TBook book in lib)
        {
            writerToFile.Write(book.Title);
            writerToFile.Write(book.Author);
            writerToFile.Write(book.Genre);
            writerToFile.Write(book.BookID);
        }
        writerToFile.Close();
        currentFile.Close();
    }
```

However, when trying to read the binary file and load contents into a list, i get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.EndOfStreamException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.

Here is my subroutine that attempts to read the Binary File back into a Struct again:

```
static List<TBook> LoadDataFromFile (List<TBook>library)
    {
        FileStream currentFile;
        BinaryReader readerFromFile;
        currentFile = new FileStream("MyLibrary.bin", FileMode.Open);
        readerFromFile= new BinaryReader(currentFile);

        while (currentFile.Position < currentFile.Length)
        {
            TBook CurrentRecord = new TBook();
            CurrentRecord.Title = readerFromFile.ReadString();
            CurrentRecord.Author = readerFromFile.ReadString();
            CurrentRecord.Genre = readerFromFile.ReadString();
            CurrentRecord.BookID = readerFromFile.ReadInt16();
            library.Add(CurrentRecord);                
       }

        readerFromFile.Close();
        currentFile.Close();
        return library;
    }
```

I assume the issue is with the line:

```
while (currentFile.Position < currentFile.Length)
```

Note: The Struct is setup as follows:

```
struct TBook
    {
        public string Title;
        public string Author;
        public string Genre;
        public int BookID;
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good way to serialize your data to files. If you still want to use the binary format, you should (de)serialize the whole object graph using `BinaryFormatter` and not process each property manually. BTW, don't use `struct`s.

Comment: The issue is with ID.  You are writing an integer but reading a short.

Comment: The smells like homework, since a Serializer would do the job so much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are serializing data as binary, your deserialization code must follow serialization code exactly; otherwise your deserializer starts reading junk from adjacent positions, eventually causing an exception or silently populating your structures with wrong data.

This pair of calls is mismatched:

```
writerToFile.Write(book.BookID);
....
CurrentRecord.BookID = readerFromFile.ReadInt16();
```

It is hard to see this problem, because `BinaryWriter` overloads the `Write` method. Since `book.BookID` is of type `int`, an alias for [`Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32?view=netframework-4.7.2), the call to `Write` is resolved to `Write(Int32)`. Therefore, the corresponding read must also read `Int32`, not `Int16`:

```
CurrentRecord.BookID = readerFromFile.ReadInt32();
```